# Depth of the winding river... Not satisfied with answer...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, education, graphing-functions

I'm currently studying for the SAT.  I'm taking a practice quiz and came across this problem:

[image]

Now, using simple logic (and a bit of cheating by trial and error) we can easily determine the answer to be **(D) 20 feet**.  This seems to be the only explanation I can find.  [See here](http://talk.collegeconfidential.com/sat-act-tests-test-preparation/963694-another-sat-question.html).  There has just always been a true mathematical explanation.  I'm sure this one does too.  My first thought is to use proportions but I can't seem to get it right.

So, I'm not asking for an answer here, I wanted to know how to properly do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase "decreased 10 percent" means that the difference in the depths from 3pm to 4pm, which is 2 feet (from the two vertical intervals on the graph), is 10% or $\frac{1}{10}$ of the depth at 3pm.  So, the depth at 3pm is $10\times 2=20$ feet and the depth at 4pm is 10% or 2 feet less, so **18 feet** (choice C).

Comment: Ha!  I feel incredibly dumb!  Such an obvious question.  My mistake, I was reading too far into the question.